# How to use TextAction

Tags: java, swing, action, key-bindings, jtextcomponent

What are the purposes of using [TextAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/TextAction.html) from [AbstractAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractAction.html)? and how to use it for the following:

- Caret
- Selection in the [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html)
- KeyBindings

Comment: +1, please undo my edit if it's not valid :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While composing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10160836/230513), I recalled a venerable [`HTMLDocumentEditor`](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=1&thread=1276) by Charles Bell that illustrates the typical usage of the subclasses found in [`javax.swing.text.TextAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/TextAction.html). That editor is listed among the credits of [`Metaphase Editor`](http://kenai.com/projects/metaphaseeditor). This related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8534162/230513) showing actions found in [`StyledEditorKit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledEditorKit.html) follows the same approach. All such actions are suitable for [*Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), and all operate on the current selection maintained by the `Caret`, whenever possible.

Comment: sorry my endless lazyness, today I tested that

Comment: Glad it helped; see also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10568672/230513).

Answer (score 6):

From [Java Swing 2nd Edition](http://www.manning.com/robinson2/):

> All text components share a set of default Actions. Each of these
>   Actions are instances of TextAction by default. JTextComponent
>   provides a private static EditorKit which consists of a set of four
>   pre-built TextActions shared by all text components through the use of
>   a default Keymap instance.
>
> JTextComponent maintains a private reference to the text component
>   that most recently had the keyboard focus. TextActions are designed to
>   take advantage of this, and each TextAction will operate on this
>   component when it’s invoked in the event that the source of the
>   invoking event is not a text component.

Here are some examples that implement [TextAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/TextAction.html):

[Custom Editing Command](http://exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/javax.swing.text/CreateCmd.html)

[Finding Word Boundaries](http://exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/javax.swing.text/FindWord.html)

Comment: Here's a related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8534162/230513) showing actions found in `StyledEditorKit`.