# Java - How to hook into the Copy and Paste menu on the Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, swing

I understand that you can:

```
// Where CustomMacOSXController implements implements MRJAboutHandler, ...
CustomMacOSXController macOSXController = new CustomMacOSXController()

MRJApplicationUtils.registerAboutHandler(macOSXController); 
MRJApplicationUtils.registerPrefsHandler(macOSXController);
//... and so on
```

However I can't find anything to hook the copy and paste menu so that when it's called, the currently selected JTextField will be affected (for example the paste will paste the clipboard into the selected JTextField.

Answer (score 4):

Unlike the Mac OS X System and Application menu, the Edit menu is entirely under the purview of your program. You have to create and populate it with the approariate [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html). The pre-defined subclasses defined in [`javax.swing.text.TextAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/TextAction.html) are handy, as they are aware of the focused component. See also this related [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10075147/230513) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8534162/230513). For example,

```
Action pasteAction = new DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction();
JMenuItem pasteItem = new JMenuItem(pasteAction);
JButton pasteButton = new JButton(pasteAction);
```

Addendum: To fully integrate your Edit menu into Mac OS X, you must tell the operating system to use your menu, using one of the approaches shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8956715/230513). To obtain the platform-dependent modifier key, use `getMenuShortcutKeyMask()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10161155/230513). Finally, Charles Bell's [`HTMLDocumentEditor`](http://www.artima.com/forums/flat.jsp?forum=1&thread=1276) is an example that uses the [text actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/TextAction.html).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you're saying. In this case you're attaching an Action to a new JMenuItem and JButton, but it doesn't link it up to the Copy and Paste menu in an Apple application...

Comment: See also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8956715/230513) about moving Java menus to the Mac menu bar and this [anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10161155/230513) about menu accelerators.

Comment: Seems like you had one magic box at home, from which you bring these wonderful examples here and there :-) , send me one if you can :-)

Comment: @nIcEcOw: This [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/keypad-panel) shows how to _forward_ one `Action` to another.

Comment: Ahha, this one is amazing, never used `Action` like this, one event can trigger someone else's event. That's wonderful :-)