# Java - Add accelerator to a JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, accelerator, jmenuitem

I want to set an accelerator to a JMenuItem.

Right now I am setting it like this

```
openFile.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
```

and it's working but I don't want ctrl+o as accelerator. I want 'space' as accelerator but I didn't find any method by which I can generate a KeyStroke corresponding to 'space'.

```
KeyStroke.getStroke()
```

either takes a char or (int, int). I didn't find any char corresponding to space also.

Answer (score 3):

> ..didn't find any char corresponding to space also.

[`KeyEvent.VK_SPACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_SPACE)

I would not be surprised if Swing ignores it, since `' '` is an unusual & hard to see accelerator.

Comment: I said I didn't find `char` corresponding to space. `KeyEvent.VK_SPACE` is an int and there is no method like KeyStroke.getStroke(int) which takes only int. I have to supply some modifier also which I don't want.

Comment: So let me get this straight.  If the user tabs to a button and presses 'pace' to activate it, you want to invoke the menu action?  Let me upgrade 'unusual & hard to see accelerator' to 'unworkable GUI'.  My advice is 'choose a workable accelerator letter'.  What is the text shown in the menu item?

Comment: +1 for thinking of the user. :-) More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10161155/230513).

Comment: hmm ... didn't try just assuming: the display name is _Space_ not empty :-)

Answer (score 3):

Most UI delegates render a `KeyEvent.VK_SPACE` accelerator using something like the `METRICAL TETRASEME`: ⏘ ([`U+23D8`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/23d8/index.htm)). For example, an [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) might include these lines:

```
static final int MASK = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask();
putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, MASK));
```

Comment: Note that Mac OS X uses this accelerator to start a [spotlight search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotlight_%28software%29).