# Paste menu item, not doing anything when attached to a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, key-bindings, jpopupmenu

I have a JTextField, paste automatically works using Cntl-V because of inbuilt support within Swing. But I additionally need a popupmenu to help users not so familiar with shortcut keys. The following code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestPopup
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTextField widget      = new JTextField(50);
        final JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        popup.add(widget.getActionMap().get("paste"));
        widget.add(popup);
        widget.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);
        frame.add(widget);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

displays the paste option but does nothing when selected.
Also note is is displayed as 'paste' rather than 'Paste'

What am I doing wrong ?

*** Solution ***

Nevermind, got it working, using DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction instead of "paste" makes the paste works, (unclear to me what the "paste" action actually does as it exists)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestPopup
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTextField widget      = new JTextField(50);
        final JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        popup.add(widget.getActionMap().get(DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction));
        widget.add(popup);
        widget.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);
        frame.add(widget);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

but this will not fix the name problem, to do this I introduced menu item

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit;
import java.awt.*;

public class TestPopup
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTextField widget      = new JTextField(50);
        final JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem pasteMenuItem = new JMenuItem(widget.getActionMap().get(DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction));
        pasteMenuItem.setText("Paste");
        popup.add(pasteMenuItem);

        widget.setComponentPopupMenu(popup);
        frame.add(widget);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @mKorbel i dont follow

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: `JtextField widget      = new JTextField(50);`  BTW - that would not compile.  Please stop wasting our time with uncompilable code snippets that are 'something vaguely like' the actual code being used.

Comment: @AndrewThompson fixed example

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ive now modified to SSCE

Comment: Did you mean `DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction`?

Comment: A complete example is cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10160836/230513).

Comment: @CatalinaIsland no i meant DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to notice that `DefaultEditorKit.pasteAction` is the *name* of the `Action`, `"paste-from-clipboard"`. It may be easier to set the menu item's `Action` directly:

```
JMenuItem pasteMenuItem = new JMenuItem(new DefaultEditorKit.PasteAction());
```