# Java "Save" vs "Save As" Strategies

Tags: java, swing, save, savefiledialog, save-as

I am building a basic paint application and have implemented Open and Save functionality, however, I would like to add in "Save As." Essentially, Save As would always make use of JFileChooser, but Save would automatically write to file if a file already exists and is currently being edited.

With that said, what strategies can I invoke to streamline this process? Obviously, Save As is already complete per the implementation of the Save feature I have already written (I apologize if that wording is confusing). However, in order to make the "Save" feature function as I intend it to, I believe I would need a way to keep track of whether or not the file exists and is currently being edited.

So what is a good way to keep track of whether or not a file exists and is currently loaded--and if it is, the Save function will write without JFileChooser, but if it isn't, it will launch the Save As functionality.

For what its worth, the Save feature, as highlighted, should apply when the Open dialog is called, so I could keep track of this somehow. I am also Opening bufferedimages and laying them as TexturePaint over my shape objects. So when the above happens is when I want the Save dialog to work as a "normal" save function, so that is another feature to take into consideration.

However, I would really like to learn about some good strategies to accomplish this in a more generic sense. Thus far, I have come up empty handed.

Comment: `HTMLDocumentEditor` is a complete example, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10160836/230513).

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field to the object that stores the file name, and it's only set when you Open a file, or when you use Save As.  Then, if the file name is null, clicking on Save actually calls Save As's code instead.