# JTextField not displaying super/subscript

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class practice9 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JButton b = new JButton();
    b.setBounds(10, 10, 150, 150);
    JLabel l = new JLabel("ell");
    l.setText("<html>+ax<sup>2</sup>+bx<sub>2</sub>+c</html>");
    b.add(l);
    JTextField t = new JTextField();
    t.setBounds(10, 300, 150, 150);
    t.add(l);

    JFrame f = new JFrame("");

    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setLayout(null);

    f.setBounds(10, 10, 500, 500);
    f.add(b);
    f.add(t);
}
}
```

I was working on a calculator and wanted to display superscripts. I was successful in doing so on a label using the HTML, but failed to repeat it on a text field.

Is it impossible to do it in a text field (i.e. display sub/superscript) or is there a way?

Comment: please don't use `null` layout. call `f.setVisible(true)` in the end after adding all the component.

Comment: that doesn't answer the question ,does it :P :D

Comment: That's why I suggested it in comment instead of an answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `JTextField` doesn't support this because it's using a `PlainDocument`

Comment: @user2837260 The suggestion not to use a `null` layout may not answer this question, but it's likely to answer a lot more in the future ;)

Comment: so my only option is to replace the textfield of my calculator with a JLabel?

Comment: but i like working with 'null' layout..it gives me the freedom to place stuff on the frame wherever i want!!

Comment: absolute positioning might work on your system but think about other system that have different resolution and OS. What about if I re-size the frame?

Comment: Please have a look at [Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) that supports HTML formatting.

Comment: And different fonts and rendering pipelines, all these things change the amount of space components need. Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion on modern GUI design

Comment: i see what you are getting at raj bhadur :D

Comment: @Braj The trick would be keeping to a single row height and allowing it to overflow...

Comment: `HTMLDocumentEditor` is a complete example, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10167091/230513).

Comment: As an aside, the logic used in that code is hard to understand.  For example.  1) Why try to add a `JLabel` to a `JButton` when we can simply call `b.setText("..")`?  A button is one of the components that *does* support (simple) HTML.  2) Why have such a 'tall' `JTextField` that can only accept a single line of text, then give it a small (standard) font?

Comment: this was just a dummy code..to sort things out for the main project..

Comment: Well now is the time to sort out crap code & get the design right, no?

Comment: As an aside, a tip.  Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever - the `@` is important) to *notify* a person of a new comment.

Comment: aye aye @AndrewThompson