# Need help implementing mouselistener in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jtextarea

Hello guys i am writing a simple gui editor in java swing using JTextArea. but now i want to be able to right click and have the options to cut, copy, paste and select all and possibly change fonts. I need help in implementing the option of cutting, copying or pasting in the JTextArea. Help will be appreciated. 
Below is a snippet of my code:

```
public class Example extends JPanel
{
    private JTextArea area;
    private JScrollPane scpane;

    public Example()
    {
        super("My Text Editor");
        setUp();
    }

    private void setUp()
    {
        area = new JTextArea();
        scpane= new JScrollPane(area);

        area.addMouseListener(
            new MouseAdapter()
            {
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    if(e.getButton()==MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
                    {
                        //having difficulty how to set up the copy, cut or paste option 
                        //with the mouse in JTextArea.
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I need help in implementing the option.."*  SO is not a help desk, it is a Q&A Site.  Throw 'right click java' into your favorite search engine and follow the 5 top links.  Try something yourself.  Get back to us when you have a specific *question* and an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) of your attempt.  Voting to close this as 'too broad'.

Answer (score 3):

Start by taking a look at [`JComponent#setComponentPopupMenu`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setComponentPopupMenu(javax.swing.JPopupMenu)) which will allow you to associate a `JPopupMenu` with a component and have it automatically displayed when the user triggers the appropriate, system specific, trigger.

Next, take a look at:

- [`JTextArea#copy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#copy())
- [`JTextArea#cut`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#cut())
- [`JTextArea#past`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#paste())
- [`JTextArea#selectAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#selectAll())

Now, if you're really clever, you would extract the associated `Action`s for the copy/cut/paste operations of the `JTextArea`s key bindings are wrap your own `Action` around them, appling those to your `JPopupMenu` and get it all for free...

For example...

```
    JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
    ActionMap am = ta.getActionMap();

    Action paste = am.get("paste-from-clipboard");
    Action copy = am.get("copy-to-clipboard");
    Action cut = am.get("cut-to-clipboard");
```

See [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: See also the example(s) cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10167091/230513).